# MySQL custom storage path

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a server with almost no free space on it, so I attached a NFS volume to it. Now I would like MySQL to be storing tables or, even better, entire databases on the shared volume. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea. You will have performance and consistency issues if storage is on **NFS**. Consider adding a secondary local disk, mounting it, and hosting your database files in it.

Having said that, you could change database location in MySQL. It's pretty simple. Have a look at [this web entry](http://developer.spikesource.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_change_the_mysql_database_location). MySQL is pretty flexible with this kind of things.

Comment: On Linux/Unix systems you can put the datafiles anywhere (everywhere) and just use symlinks from the defined datadir. Agreed, **putting DBMS data files on a network filesystem is very stupid** not just for performance - it also causes concurrency problems

Comment: If you blindly use symlinks and change database location you will incur into a major SELinux no-no, since the only folder the mysql daemon can access is by default /etc/